# defining a fuction to be used in solving equation from a data file

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I am completely new to python and in fact any fundamental programming language, I use Mathematica for my all my symbolic and numeric calculations. I am learning to work with python and finding it really awesome! Here is a problem I am trying to solve but stuck without a clue!
I have a data file for example

```
0.      1.    
0.01    0.9998000066665778    
0.02    0.9992001066609779    
...     ..
```

Which just the {t, Cos[2t]}.
I want to define a function out of this data and use it in solving an equation in python. My Mathematica intuition tells me that I should define the function like:

```
    iFunc[x_] = Interpolation[iData, x]
```

and rest of the job is easy. for instance

```
NDSolve[{y''[x] + iFunc[x] y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y[1] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Solves the equation easily. (I have not tried with more complicated cases though).
Now how to do the job in python and also accuracy is an important issue for me. So, now I would like to ask two questions.

**1. Is this the most accurate method in Mathematica?**

**2. And what is the equivalent of more accurate way to do the problem in python?**

Here is my humble attempt to solve the problem (with a lot of input from StackOverflow)  where the definition with cos(2t) works:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import cos
from scipy import interpolate

data = np.genfromtxt('cos2t.dat')

T = data[:,0]  #first column
phi = data[:,1]  #second column

f = interpolate.interp1d(T, phi)

tmin = 0.0# There should be a better way to define from the data
dt = 0.01
tmax = 2*np.pi
t = np.arange(tmin, tmax, dt) 

phinew = f(t)   # use interpolation function returned by `interp1d`

"""
def fun(z, t):
    x, y = z
    return np.array([y, -(cos(2*t))*x ])
"""    
def fun(z, t):
    x, y = z
    return np.array([y, -(phinew(t))*x ])    

sol1 = odeint(fun, [1, 0], t)[..., 0]
    
# for checking the plots        
plt.plot(t, sol1, label='sol')
plt.show()
```

---

*When I run the code with interpolated function from cos(2t) data, is not working...the error message tell

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "testde.py", line 30, 
     in <module> sol1 = odeint(fun, [1, 0], t)[..., 0] 
File "/home/archimedes/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scip‌​y/integrate/odepack.‌​py", 
    line 215, in odeint ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords) 
File "testde.py", 
    line 28, in fun return np.array([y, -(phinew(t))*x ])
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable.
```

I really can't decipher them. Please help...

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: The code with interpolation is not working...the error message tell 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testde.py", line 30, in <module>
    sol1 = odeint(fun, [1, 0], t)[..., 0]
  File "/home/archimedes/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py", line 215, in odeint
    ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords)
  File "testde.py", line 28, in fun
    return np.array([y, -(phinew(t))*x ])    
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable.
I really can't decipher them

Comment: Please add additional information to your question. There you also have better formatting. I did that for you for the error message, feel free to edit your text around it.

Comment: Thnaks @LutzL..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To sub-question 2**

With

```
t = np.arange(tmin, tmax, dt) 

phinew = f(t)   # use interpolation function returned by `interp1d`
```

equivalent to

```
phinew = np.array([ f(s) for s in t])
```

you construct `phinew` not as callable function but as array of values, closing the circle array to interpolation function to array. Use `f` which is a scalar function directly in the derivatives function,

```
def fun(z, t):
    x, y = z
    return np.array([y, -f(t)*x ])
```

Comment: I have modified the code as you suggested. Now the following error is showing
  File "testde.py", line 39, in <module>
    sol1 = odeint(fun, [1, 0], t)[..., 0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py", line 215, in odeint
    ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords)
  File "testde.py", line 37, in fun
    return np.array([y, -f(t)*x ])   
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/polyint.py", line 80, in __call__
    y = self._evaluate(x)

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 586, in _evaluate
    below_bounds, above_bounds = self._check_bounds(x_new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 618, in _check_bounds
    raise ValueError("A value in x_new is above the interpolation "
ValueError: A value in x_new is above the interpolation range.

Comment: That happens because odeint resp. lsoda uses adaptive step sizes and the internal steps can leave the bounds of the integration interval. Make the sample point interval for `cos2t.dat` larger (or the integration interval smaller by the same amount), even one point as in the simulated `T = np.arange(tmin, tmax+dt, dt); phi = np.cos(2*T)`, and it works without error.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I need to check for larger dt, however taking dt to be 1 also seems not to be working. Isn't there a way to solve it in python as the present one is just a prototype of more complicated ones which I need to solve. And I need a general approach.

Comment: Your interpolation function needs to cover input arguments as large as `tmax+dt`, which depends on the size of `dt`. There is no fixed relation between the stepping of the interpolation samples and `dt`.

Answer (score 1):

In Mathematica, the usual way is simply

```
iFunc = Interpolation[iData]
```

`Interpolation[iData]` already returns a function.

Comment: Any way to have a check on accuracy? I can think of only plotting the data with interpolation curve.

Comment: I don't understand what it means "to check accuracy". The interpolation will pass through all your data points. Maybe you want fitting instead of interpolation?

Comment: What I meant is that, is the 'usual way' is also the best way in Mathematica? I have tried to look at the Wolfram documentation and it pretty much describes everything. But for me, it seems a too simple solution for a complicated problem or maybe this is the way Mathematica is!

Comment: What do you mean by "best way"?  In what way is this solution not satisfactory?

Comment: This solution is satisfactory and I can check it with the analytic solution. But let's say, I have a data generated from a typical Differential equation of which I don't know the analytic solution. Now, is Interpolation[data] is the only method available to represent the data as a function?