# Solving a boundary value problem DE in python

Tags: python, differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following set of DE's:

```
dx' = cos(a)
dy' = sin(a)
dF' = - b * x * cos(a) + sin(a)
da' = (b * x * sin(a) + cos(a)) / F
```

with the conditions:

```
x(0) = y(0) = x(1) = 0
y(1) = 0.6
F(0) = 0.38
a(0) = -0.5
```

I tried following [a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60453812/solving-set-of-boundary-value-problems), but I just can't get it to work. Is it possible, that my F(0) and a(0) are completely off, I am not even sure about them.

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

beta = 5

def fun(x, y):
    x, dx, y, dy,  F, dF, a, da, = y;
    dxds=np.cos(a)
    dyds=np.sin(a)
    dFds=-beta * x * np.cos(a) + np.sin(a)
    dads=(beta * x * np.sin(a) + np.cos(a) ) / F

    return dx, dxds, dy, dyds, dF, dFds, da, dads

def bc(ya, yb):

    return ya[0], yb[0], ya[2], yb[2] + 0.6, ya[4] + 1, yb[4] + 1, ya[6], yb[6]

x = np.linspace(0, 0.5, 10)
y = np.zeros((8, x.size))
y[4] = 0.38
y[6] = 2.5

res = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y)
print(res.message)
x_plot = np.linspace(0, 0.5, 200)
plt.plot(x_plot, res.sol(x_plot)[0])
```

Comment: What's the problem? Why is it not working?

Comment: What is the meaning of `x, dx, y, dy,  F, dF, a, da, = y;`?

Comment: What exactly are the boundary conditions and what are the guesses of the solution? Your system has 4 equations and one parameter, in the implementation the DE are second order, so you need 8 or 9 boundary conditions, you gave only 6. Also, the BC in the text are different from the BC in the code, please make that consistent.

Comment: Your code works perfectly well, where exactly do expectations and results differ?

Comment: @MikeO'Connor : It is unpacking the state vector into the individual position and velocity variables, tuple assignment.

Comment: @LutzLehmann the problem are the conditions F and a. As I understand the problem F(0) and a(0) are the starting parameters and don't have boundary values. I should get something like this: [link](https://i.ibb.co/x121SdH/Capture.png).

It is supposed to be a rope, tied at two points to a rotating post. F(0) is the force at the top knot and a(0) the angle of the rope, again at the top knot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have foremost a physics problem, translating the physical situation into an ODE system.

`x(s)` and `y(s)` are the coordinates of the rope where `s` is the length along the rope. Consequently, `(x'(s),y'(s))` is a unit vector that is uniquely characterized by its angle `a(s)`, giving

```
    x'(s) = cos(a(s))
    y'(s) = sin(a(s))
```

To get the shape, one now has to consider the mechanics. The assumption seems to be that the rope rotates without spiraling around the rotation axis, staying in one plane. Additionally, from the equilibrium of forces you also get that the other two equations are indeed first order, not second order equations. So your state only has 4 components and the ODE system function thus has to be

```python
def fun(s, u):
    x, y, F, a = u;
    dxds=np.cos(a)
    dyds=np.sin(a)
    dFds=-beta * x * np.cos(a) + np.sin(a)
    dads=(beta * x * np.sin(a) + np.cos(a) ) / F

    return dxds, dyds, dFds, dads
```

Now there are only 4 boundary condition slots available, which are the coordinates of the start and end of the rope.

```python
def bc(ua, ub):
    return ua[0], ub[0], ua[1], ub[1] - 0.6
```

Additionally, the interval length for `s` is also the rope length, so a value of 0.5 is impossible for the given coordinates on the pole, try 1.0. There is some experimentation needed to get an initial guess that does not lead to a singular Jacobian in the BVP solver. In the end I get the solution in the x-y plane

[image]

with the components

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I however still can't get the correct result. Initial guesses about F(0) and a(0) you mean? Desperate I tried looping through several hundred F and a around 0.4 and -0.5 with no luck. In every case I got a singular Jacobian. Does the number of breakpoints play a vital role? You used 22, correct?. I am missing something else. I will work on the problem, but any additional help would be great.

Comment: This might be a case where single shooting works better than the integrated multiple shooting of the standard bvp solvers. I'll look in the possibility of making the length variable. // The initialization is with an ODE solution with 10 points, where a suitable one was determined by trying several graphs.

Comment: Yes, single shooting using `scipy.optimize.fsolve` as non-linear solver works a little bit more robustly. However, non-physical initial points still lead to strange failed solutions.

Comment: Hello, @LutzLehmann I have learned a lot from your answer. Allow me to make question here. How do you proceed if having `fun()` with extra arguments? In my case I have `fun(u,t,A,B,D,y)` being A,B,D scalars and y an array. How can I use your code for my case? Thanks

Comment: @AndresValdez : As little as there is of general code. Yes, using parameters is possible. The newer scipy procedures are trending to add back the `args=` optional argument, `solve_ivp` has it, `solve_bvp` not yet. So you have to use a `lambda` construct as wrapper, `lambda u,t: fun(u,t,A,B,D,y)`. This changes if the parameters are actually also to be fitted, then use the `p=` optional parameter, but take care to define the functions accordingly.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thanks will give a try on that

Comment: @LutzLehmann I tried to combine your advice with this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734783/9185675]. In my case I have `solve_bvp(lambda y , t: adj_sys(y,t,voc_sol,data,A,B,D),lambda y0, y1, y2, y3: bc(y0, y1, y2, y3),t, voc_sol)`, Notice that `voc_sol` has 4 arrays of Nsize, but `y` has one array of Nsize... How can I do it properly?

Comment: Hopefully you used the correct argument order, `t,y`. I was apparently stuck on the order for `odeint`. `bc` should only have 2 argument arrays, the method does not support multi-point conditions (like matlab's bvp4c does). About the array question see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61046965/scipy-odeint-different-values-of-arguments-in-each-timestep, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830215/defining-a-fuction-to-be-used-in-solving-equation-from-a-data-file

Comment: @LutzLehmann the fact is that my `adj_sys()` must return 4 first order derivatives `return [x_adj_der,u_adj_der,y_adj_der,v_adj_der]`

Comment: That does not make sense, the ODE function should have as variable input `t` and the vector `[x,u,y,v]` of length 4, this is the basis of being an ODE function. One can not predict where this ODE function will be evaluated, so any data series has to be enhanced to some kind of interpolation function. Essentially, you can not use `data[n]`, as `n` is not given in the function arguments. You have to translate `t` into `n` and then find an associated intermediate value, which is the nature of interpolation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229833/discussion-between-andres-valdez-and-lutz-lehmann).

Comment: @LutzLehmann, after our talk I posted a new question. I will appreciate if you can guide me to "join" in one big `solve_bvp()` statement... as you suggested me. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/q/66606600/9185675